# Can you explain this castle windsor registration?

Tags: castle-windsor

I am referring to [this](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx) tutorial.

At the [beginning](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-three-writing-your-first-installer.ashx) the IController types are registered as:

```
public class ControllersInstaller:IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn<IController>()
                            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

But later The EventRepository is registered as below:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .Where(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<EventRepository>())
                            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                            .LifestyleTransient()));
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two? I tried using the method used for IController registration to register IEventRepository but it doesn't work? Why?

Now in case of IEventRepository, its implementation EventRepository is used in the registration. If I implement another class say AnotherEventRepository, then I will have to add another registration for that. Can't we use a single registration to register all types of IEventRepository.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to registrer all classes implementing IEventRepository you need to add BasedOn as above. Don't forget the Where you added... That means you are considering only classes belonging to that ns.

Answer (score 0):

The first registration is pretty straightforward. You just register all classes implementing `IController` interface. Those classes are also they services. So if you want to resolve eg. `HomeController` you just call `container.Resolve<HomeController>()`.

The second registration takes all classes from the namespace where the `EventRepository` is declared and registers them with [default interfaces](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_DefaultInterfaces__6). So if you want to resolve `EventRepository` you have to call `container.Resolve<IEventRepository>()`.

In case of `AnotherEventRepository` you don't have to add another registration if it is in the same namespace. But if it also implements `IEventRepository` you won't actually know which implementations will be resolved.